# Error parsing regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a simple regex in c# to locate backslashes not preceded or followed by any backslashes:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(".*(?<!\\)\\(?!\\).*");
```

However, this statment generates an ArgumentException: "parsing ".(?" - Not enough )'s"

The group parentheses seem to match.  Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the @ symbol in front of your string, otherwise you need to double-escape the slashes (once for C#, and once for Regex).

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@".*(?<!\\)\\(?!\\).*");
```

or

```
Regex reg = new Regex(".*(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?!\\\\).*");
```

Comment: thank goodness for string literals, double escaping just makes these more difficult to parse (for humans that is)

Answer (score 4):

use the string literal @

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@".*(?<!\\)\\(?!\\).*");
```